# Cannot find libxml2 in android ndk project

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, libxml2

Good day Everyone. I have wasted almost a week now figuring what's wrong when i try adding libxml2 to my android ndk project.

```
 LOCAL_PATH     := $(call my-dir)
    #BUILDING LIBXML2
     include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := xml2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  $(LOCAL_PATH)/libxml2/libxml2.a
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libxml2/include
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libxml2/include
LOCAL_DISABLE_FORMAT_STRING_CHECKS := true  
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
#BUILDING SOME SPICE CODES
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LIB_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/armeabi

SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS   := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/deps

spice_objs := \
                   $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/lib/libssl.a \
                   $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/lib/libcrypto.a \
                   $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/lib/libcelt051.a 

LOCAL_MODULE    := spice

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := channel-record.c channel-playback.c channel-cursor.c \
                   spice-cmdline.c coroutine_gthread.c spice-util.c \
                   spice-session.c spice-channel.c spice-marshal.c spice-glib-enums.c \
                   common/generated_client_demarshallers.c common/generated_client_demarshallers1.c \
                   common/generated_client_marshallers.c common/generated_client_marshallers1.c \
                   gio-coroutine.c channel-base.c channel-main.c spice-proxy.c bio-gsocket.c glib-compat.c \
                   channel-display.c channel-display-mjpeg.c channel-inputs.c decode-glz.c \
                   decode-jpeg.c decode-zlib.c wocky-http-proxy.c channel-port.c spice-client.c spice-audio.c \
                   common/mem.c common/marshaller.c common/canvas_utils.c common/backtrace.c \
                   common/sw_canvas.c common/pixman_utils.c common/lines.c common/rop3.c common/quic.c \
                   common/lz.c common/region.c common/ssl_verify.c common/log.c spice-gstaudio.c

LOCAL_LDLIBS    += $(spice_objs) \
                   -ljnigraphics -llog -ldl -lstdc++ -lz -lc \
                   -malign-double -malign-loops
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -L$(LIB_PATH) -lgstreamer_android

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  += -DG_LOG_DOMAIN=\"GSpice\" \
                   -DSW_CANVAS_CACHE \
                   -DSPICE_GTK_LOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" \
                   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -UHAVE_SYS_SHM_H -DSW_CANVAS_CACHE  \
                   -D_REENTRANT -DWITH_GSTAUDIO

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/common \
                    $(SPICE_CLIENT_ANDROID_DEPS)/include

LOCAL_CFLAGS    :=  $(LOCAL_CPPFLAGS) \
                   -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wl,--no-undefined \
                   -fPIC -DPIC -O3 -funroll-loops -ffast-math

LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS += $(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_LDLIBS)
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := gstreamer_android
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
#BUILDING SOME MINE C CODE   --------Here i add Mine C file and xml2 for it
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := start-spice
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := start-spice.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES= xml2
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
#BUILDING SPICE ANDROID
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := spice-android
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := android/android-service.c android/android-spicy.c android/android-spice-widget.c \
                   android/android-io.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := spice
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
ifndef GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT
ifndef GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID
$(error GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID is not defined!)
endif
GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID)
endif
GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH  := $(GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT)/share/gst-android/ndk-build/
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/plugins.mk
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS         := $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS) jpeg
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_DEPS      := glib-2.0 gthread-2.0 pixman-1 gstreamer-app-0.10

include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/gstreamer.mk
```

So even after I add xml2.so as shared library to my project - nothing happens. It strill cannot find libs  and gives me tons of this

```
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libstart-spice.so
/opt/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/obj/local/armeabi/objs/start-spice/start-spice.o: in function create_request:/opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/jni/src/start-spice.c:251: error: undefined reference to 'xmlNewDoc'
/opt/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/obj/local/armeabi/objs/start-spice/start-spice.o: in function create_request:/opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/jni/src/start-spice.c:252: error: undefined reference to 'xmlNewNode'
/opt/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/obj/local/armeabi/objs/start-spice/start-spice.o: in function create_request:/opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/jni/src/start-spice.c:253: error: undefined reference to 'xmlNodeSetContent'
/opt/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/obj/local/armeabi/objs/start-spice/start-spice.o: in function create_request:/opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/jni/src/start-spice.c:254: error: undefined reference to 'xmlDocSetRootElement'
/opt/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/obj/local/armeabi/objs/start-spice/start-spice.o: in function create_request:/opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/jni/src/start-spice.c:255: error: undefined reference to 'xmlDocDumpFormatMemory'
/opt/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/obj/local/armeabi/objs/start-spice/start-spice.o: in function create_request:/opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/jni/src/start-spice.c:256: error: undefined reference to 'xmlFreeDoc'
/opt/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/obj/local/armeabi/objs/start-spice/start-spice.o: in function Java_com_iiordanov_bVNC_NativeCalls_getPortAndPassword:/opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/jni/src/start-spice.c:144: error: undefined reference to 'xmlReadMemory'
/opt/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/obj/local/armeabi/objs/start-spice/start-spice.o: in function Java_com_iiordanov_bVNC_NativeCalls_getPortAndPassword:/opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/jni/src/start-spice.c:153: error: undefined reference to 'xmlDocGetRootElement'
/opt/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/obj/local/armeabi/objs/start-spice/start-spice.o: in function Java_com_iiordanov_bVNC_NativeCalls_getPortAndPassword:/opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/jni/src/start-spice.c:163: error: undefined reference to 'xmlHasProp'
/opt/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/obj/local/armeabi/objs/start-spice/start-spice.o: in function Java_com_iiordanov_bVNC_NativeCalls_getPortAndPassword:/opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/jni/src/start-spice.c:170: error: undefined reference to 'xmlHasProp'
/opt/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/obj/local/armeabi/objs/start-spice/start-spice.o: in function Java_com_iiordanov_bVNC_NativeCalls_getPortAndPassword:/opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/jni/src/start-spice.c:172: error: undefined reference to 'xmlGetProp'
/opt/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/obj/local/armeabi/objs/start-spice/start-spice.o: in function Java_com_iiordanov_bVNC_NativeCalls_getPortAndPassword:/opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/jni/src/start-spice.c:182: error: undefined reference to 'xmlHasProp'
/opt/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/obj/local/armeabi/objs/start-spice/start-spice.o: in function Java_com_iiordanov_bVNC_NativeCalls_getPortAndPassword:/opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/jni/src/start-spice.c:184: error: undefined reference to 'xmlGetProp'
/opt/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/obj/local/armeabi/objs/start-spice/start-spice.o: in function Java_com_iiordanov_bVNC_NativeCalls_getPortAndPassword:/opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/jni/src/start-spice.c:221: error: undefined reference to 'xmlFreeDoc'
/opt/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/obj/local/armeabi/objs/start-spice/start-spice.o: in function Java_com_iiordanov_bVNC_NativeCalls_getPortAndPassword:/opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/jni/src/start-spice.c:234: error: undefined reference to 'xmlFreeDoc'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/opt/Test6/bVNC/eclipse_projects/bVNC/obj/local/armeabi/libstart-spice.so] Error 1
```

С code header in start-spice looks something like this:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
```

And i in java code i add:

```
 static
    {
       System.loadLibrary("start-spice");
    }
```

Would be really really gratefull if someone helped!

Comment: Try to add `-lxml2` to `LOCAL_LDLIBS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is issue of linking shared libraries, you need to add `LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LIB_PATH) -lxm2` just before `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES= xml2` .

Answer (score 2):

If you have the prebuilt static library for Android in `$(LOCAL_PATH)/libxml2/libxml2.a`, you can use it as is in your **spice-android** project,

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += xml2
```

Instead of `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)` for **xml2**, use

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  libxml2/libxml2.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

If you have a strong reason to use **xml2** as a separate shared library, you need to add call

```
System.loadLibrary("xml2");
```

to your Java code (before loading `libspice-android.so`) and replace `LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  $(LOCAL_PATH)/libxml2/libxml2.a` with

```
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES :=  $(LOCAL_PATH)/libxml2/libxml2.a
```