# Adding libxml support to android ndk project

Tags: android, android-ndk, libxml2

Good Day everyone. Still trying to figure out what's wrong with adding xml library.(Previos thread [Cannot find libxml2 in android ndk project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084818/cannot-find-libxml2-in-android-ndk-project))

In jni folder: i jave prebuild `libxml.so`, which i successfully builded, `android.mk` and `start-spice.c`. `Start-spice.c` needs libxml in order to work.

Android.mk:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE :=  libxml
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=libxml.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := start-spice
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := start-spice.c 
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lxml
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES= xml
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And still it says that cannot find `libxml/parser.h`

Maybe someone could tell me what's wrong?

The think is that in `.c`i use libxml methods from linux and here i downloaded libxml2 and builded it - is there any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you remembering to add the .h directories of libxml to the list of include directories for the other modules?  I don't see any -I flags or LOCAL_C_INCLUDES being set

Comment: Didn't know i had to(

Comment: Sorry but in previos post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365425/general-questions-about-android-ndk) you told that all i need to have is '.so' files? Or for this module only i have to set 'LOCAL_C_INCLUDES' to the '.h' directory?

Comment: That's if you have the .so files and are trying to call it from Java via JNI.  Is you're trying to call it from more C or C++, you need to have the appropriate header files just like any other C/C++ compilation.